# Google Play: Huawei Nexus 6P is not compatible with the app

Tags: android, google-play, nexus-6p

I have an Android app that I have restricted to only handsets.  I used the following code to only allow handsets to download the app from Google Play

```
<!-- Only permit app to be used on handsets, prevent tablets -->
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="small" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />        
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <!-- LG G3 QHD Resolution -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="xlarge" />      
    </compatible-screens>
```

Today, a user reported that Google Play is telling them their device is not compatible with the app.  They are using a Verizon Wireless Huawei Nexus 6P running Android 6.0 Marshmallow.

I'm guessing I need to add more to the  node of my manifest to support this device, however I'm not sure what the screenDensity would be for it.  How can I get this device supported by my app?

When I create an emulator for this exact device in Android Studio, the app runs on it perfectly fine.

Comment: in `build.gradle` targetsdk is 23?

Comment: @Anders, no my targetSdk is 10.  It's an app that's been around a while and stared on android 2.3.3.  Should I change the targetSDK to 23 and set the minSdk to 10?

Comment: yup u need to update the targetsdk to 23, it will most probably solve the issue

Comment: @Anders My phone is Android 5.0.2 and I have no problem downloading the app.  Just curious, why would it make a difference for Android 6?

Comment: well there is an issue with nexus 6 compatibility, u can surf about it if u want want to learn more but for now I will add a hack to get over this issue, see my answer

Comment: @Anders, thanks I'll give it a shot.  Once user confirms the issue is resolved I will mark as correct answer.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to screen size

```
<screen
    android:screenDensity="560"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
```

it will hopefully solve your issue

Comment: Curious, did this work? Does this line allow for a Nexus 6P ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to OP's question, however one of my apps had the exact same issue, without using any compatible-screens restrictions. So this might be of interests to others having the same issue

Had to add this to reach another 178 devices, including the Nexus 6P. I assume not all of them are actually required for the 6P, most likely anyDensity should be enough:

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

To support only phones, I suppose this should be enough:

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```